# React- managing arrays in react hooks

Tags: reactjs

i'm trying to make  full dropdown menu on the top

and i want to change the background of the menu item when hovering the menu

the question is that whether i can combine this 'useHover' things with array or something else so that the code looks clear.

```
    const [ref1, isHovered1] = useHover();
    const [ref2, isHovered2] = useHover();
    const [ref3, isHovered3] = useHover();
    const [ref4, isHovered4] = useHover();
    const [ref5, isHovered5] = useHover();
```

```
    <Menu ref= {ref1}>
            hello1
        </Menu>
        <Menu  ref= {ref2}>
            hello2
        </Menu>
        <Menu  ref= {ref3}>
             hello3
        </Menu>
        <Menu  ref= {ref4}>
             hello4
        </Menu>
        <Menu  ref= {ref5}>
            hello5
        </Menu>
```

here is the full code

https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-frog-5hp9c?file=/

Comment: You're already using styled-components, I don't see the point in trying to make a javascript/react handler/hook to manage an onHover state when you can more easily just leverage the CSS to change the background of a wrapper component when hovered.

Comment: @DrewReese the main problem here is that other submenus components in a different part of the tree depends on the hover state of each menu, but that code is not included in the question :| you can check the sandbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a MenuWrapper to be able to use the hook and iterate over an array of menus. Track the menus in a state and update the correspondent item in the array when hovered state from the hook changes. Then for each Submenu access the hovered state via array index.

You can check this [fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-frost-40dj1?file=/src/components/Header.jsx:2969-3278) to see it working.

```js
  const MenuWrapper = ({ label, updateMenus, index }) => {
    const [ref, isHovered] = useHover();
    useEffect(() => {
      updateMenus((menus) =>
        menus.map((m, i) => (index === i ? { ...m, hovered: isHovered } : m))
      );
    }, [updateMenus, isHovered, index]);

    return <Menu ref={ref}>{label}</Menu>;
  };
  
  ...

  const [menus, updateMenus] = useState([
    { label: "안녕", hovered: false },
    { label: "안녕1", hovered: false },
    { label: "안녕2", hovered: false },
    { label: "안녕3", hovered: false },
    { label: "안녕4", hovered: false }
  ]);

  ...

  {menus.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <MenuWrapper
        key={index}
        updateMenus={updateMenus}
        label={item.label}
        index={index}
      />
    );
  })}

  ...

  <SubMenu className={menus[0].hovered && "ih"}>
  ...
  <SubMenu className={menus[1].hovered && "ih"}>
  ...
```

The use of [portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html) also came to my mind, but it would imply some more changes

Answer (score 0):

React hook is unable to be used in loop. Create a new component:

```
const HoverMenu = ({ title }) => {
  const [hoverRef, isHovered] = useHover();

  return (
    <Menu ref={hoverRef}>
        {title}
    </Menu>
  );
}
```

Your main component:

```
...
return (
    <>
        {menus.map(menu => (
            <HoverMenu title={menu.title} />
        ))}
    </>
);
```